# How can I make my skirt with riffles?

Tags: modeling

[image: Skirt from online]
[image: Skirts]

I am trying to re-create a skirt with ruffles like the grey one above with the blue shirt, I have already run a cloth simulation, but I cannot get the shape to look right on my version of the skirt.

Everything looks very flat because I am only using two subdivided planes.

Comment: The cloth is folded on the top and then stitched together.

Comment: I've never tried the cloth simulation myself, but from what I've seen in tutorials, I don't believe achieving that skirt with a sim is impossible. Of course I could be wrong, tho.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could try it this way:

Create a cone:

[image]

Create a vertex group, that will be the cloth pin group:

[image]

Give it 2 shapekeys, select the second one and scale one vertical edge out of several (make it a bit heterogeneous):

[image]

Give your object a *Cloth* simulation, choose the group as pin group, choose *Cotton* presets for example, increase the *Quality Steps*, the *Vertex Mass*, increase the *Collisions Quality* to 4, enable *Self Collisions*. Then keyframe the second shapekey from 0 to 1:

[image]

You can add fake folds with a *Bump* node and a *Noise Texture* that you stretch on Z.