# How to animate this low-poly "floating" skirt that has a circular, wavelike motion?

Tags: animation

Here is the link https://dribbble.com/shots/14240649-Wake-up

and here a gif of how it should look like:

[image]

I am trying to create an animation like his dress , I used wave modifier but it doesn't work correctly. So anyone know how to do it

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249671/how-can-i-make-my-skirt-look-more-like-the-picture/249679#249679 Is possibly a helpful answer, but your question is unclear with the information provided.

Comment: i don't know how "perfect" it has to be, but if you are satisfied with this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY5Yc.gif i can write an answer

Comment: @Chris I don't think it is wave modifier rather than rotated curve at bottom edge ... or rotating whole object with texture with Global coordinates :)

Comment: This is absolutely possible! I have no idea how he made it, I just tried to rebuild.

Comment: @vklidu: woooow!!! very nice and very close to the original!!

Comment: @vklidu: i tried my best that the question will be reopened and i voted to reopen, so hopefully u can write an answer...because i LOVE your answer ;)

Comment: Sorry, I am new here so dont know how to post a question correctly. Thats why I just add a external link and ask how to do it. From now I will ask my questions briefly and correctly

Comment: Thank you very much @Chris . Hope to see more answers from you too in future

Comment: @ruckus sorry for unclear question , But your answer is also helpful for me , Thank you :)

Comment: @vklidu It is reopened now. Care to post that as an answer?

Comment: Done :) ... also thanks to @Chris for Q fix (I'm sure I wrote it already, but I can't see it here ... hm weird).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*One way :) ... a bit of visual illusion, but seems to be used in your reference too.*

---

- add Cube - delete bottom face, move two bottom opposite vertices up, scale down top face, add Subdivision modifier

[image]

- animate Z Rotation value of the object (by keyframe or just type expression `#frame*0.01` at the field)
- set material node tree with Texture Coordinates > Object.
  (I used Empty object, but you can use head or any other part of your character)

[image]

- additionally you can animated Z Scale (here add one keyframe and add Noise modifier to this F-curve)

[image]

Comment: just great!! +1

Comment: @vklidu
How you created that texture
I'm unable to download file

Comment: @Mrsimulation ... hm same for me, luckily I was able to restore the path to file so it works now ... basically it is based on Wave Texture ...

Comment: Hehe.. well spotted! Indeed, that looks to be the way it was done :D

Comment: @vklidu
Thank you so much :)